# How to dynamically update JLabel on changed text?

Tags: java, swing, awt, updates, jlabel

My JLabel starts out with a variable that is 0 when JLabel is drawn. Another Thread increases this value continually and I want to update the Label.

If possible I don't want the thread to access the label.
(gm.getPlayerByListIndex(index).getAlk()) gets updated

```
    createPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean checked = checkInputs(nameInput, difficultyInput);
            if (checked) {
                String playername = getInput(nameInput);
                addPlayerToMainWindow(gm.getRegisteredPlayers().size(), playername);
                gm.createPlayer(playername, Integer.parseInt(getInput(difficultyInput)));
                dialog.dispose();
                JLabel alkLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(gm.getPlayerByListIndex(index).getAlk()));
                window.getWindow().getContentPane().add(alkLabel);
                alkLabel.setVisible(true);
                alkLabel.setBounds(160, (120 * index) + 50, 100, 50);

            }
        }

    });
```

Thread that increases Valuse:

```
public class Dispenser extends Thread {

     List<Player> players = GameManager.getInstance().getRegisteredPlayers();

    public void run() {

       while (true) {
           System.out.println("alive");
           try {
               for (Player p : players) {
                   p.setAlk(p.getAlk() + p.getDifficulty()); // TODO too hard
               }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                System.out.println("playerlist in use, retry");
            }
            try {
               sleep(1000); // TODO too short
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is being referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in this case.

You will need and Observer class such as this one (**note:** this implementation assumes that `equals` and `hashCode` are implemented in the `Player` class):

```java
public class JLabelObserver{
   private JLabel label;
   private Player player;
   public JLabelObserver(JLabel label, Player player){
       this.label = label;
       this.player = player;
   }
   public update(Player player){
       if(this.player.equals(player))
           label.setText(player.getAlk())
   }
}
```

Now your dispenser class should act as the Obervable class, so you `Dispenser` would look like this:

```java
public class Dispenser extends Thread {

    List<Player> players = GameManager.getInstance().getRegisteredPlayers();
    List<JLabelObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void run() {

       while (true) {
           System.out.println("alive");
           try {
               for (Player p : players) {
                   p.setAlk(p.getAlk() + p.getDifficulty()); // TODO too hard
                   notifyObservers(p)
               }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
                System.out.println("playerlist in use, retry");
            }
            try {
               sleep(1000); // TODO too short
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
   }

   public static addObserver(JLabelObserver observer){
       observers.add(observer);
   }

   public static notifyObservers(Player player){
        for(JLabelObserver observer : observers){
             observer.update(player);
        }
   }
}
```

and finally, after you create your JLabel you also create and Observer:

```
JLabel alkLabel = new JLabel(Integer.toString(gm.getPlayerByListIndex(index).getAlk()));
JLabelObserver alkLabelObserver = new JLabelObserver(alkLabel, index);
Dispenser.addObserver(alkLabelObserver);
```